# Associated enum state in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, enums, swiftui, associated-value

How can I use an associated enum as a `@State` variable in an `if` statement in SwiftUI?

```swift
struct ProfileView: View {
    @State private var choice = Choice.simple

    private enum Choice {
        case simple
        case associated(Int)
    }

    var body: some View {
        if choice == .simple {
            Text("Simple")
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler reports this error:

> Protocol 'Equatable' requires that 'ProfileView.Choice' conform to 'Equatable'

Comment: The underlying problem turned out to that in my production code, I was using a struct (vs. Int in the repro), and the struct didn't implement `Equatable`. Then in the simplified repro, I didn't ensure there was always a root view, which happened to give the same error. This led me to think the problem was related to how `@State` was implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is fixed variant. Tested with Xcode 11.4.

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    @State private var choice = Choice.simple

    private enum Choice: Equatable {
        case simple
        case associated(Int)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if choice == .simple {
                Text("Simple")
            } else {
                Text("Other")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `if case` to check if an `enum` variable matches a certain `case`.

```
var body: some View {
    if case .simple = choice {
        return Text("Simple")
    } else {
        return Text("Not so simple")
    }
}
```

If you actually want to use the associated value to be displayed, I'd suggest using a `switch` to cover all `enum` cases.

```
var body: some View {
    let text: String
    switch choice {
    case .simple:
        text = "Simple"
    case .associated(let value):
        text = "\(value)"
    }
    return Text(text)
}
```